# How can I use a filter to all field in ng-table

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

Hi I'm learning AngularJs, and I'm using ng-table, but I do not know how to do a multiple filter in one field.

I know how to do one filter and sorting, I searched and read but I couldn't find anything working for me, I guess there is a way.

Thanks and pardon my English.

EDIT: Thats my code

$scope.init = function () { 
            $http.post(slim + 'grupos2', $.extend({}, false, window.seguridad)).then(function(response) {
                $scope.grupos = response;
                var data2 = $scope.grupos.data;

```
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,          
                count: 10,        
                filter: {

                },
                 sorting: {
                nombre: 'asc'     
                    }
            }, {
            total: data2.length, 
            getData: function($defer, params) { 

             var orderedData = params.filter() ?
                 $filter('filter')(data2, params.filter()) :
                 data2;


             orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                 $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) :
                 orderedData;

                $scope.grupete = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()); 
                params.total(orderedData.length); 
                $defer.resolve($scope.grupete); 
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
            <tr ng-repeat="grupo in grupete">
                <td data-title="'Num'" sortable="'idGrupo'">{{grupo.idGrupo}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }" >{{grupo.nombre}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Aforo'" sortable="'aforo'" >{{grupo.aforo}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Fecha'" sortable="'fecha'" >{{grupo.fecha.toString()}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

I want there to be a filter that searches multiple fields like name.

filter="{ 'name': 'text' }"

Comment: Can you post any code of what you've tried thus far?

Comment: You can chain several filters in your view by using pipe operator. It basically give output of one filter as the input of the next filter. `<tr ng-repeat="grupo in grupete | filter:params.filter | orderBy:params.orderBy()">`

Comment: forgive not understand that you have answered me cubbuk , the way you tell me is to filter and make the orderby fields as in the code that I have but I still have the same question as I do that a field is a filter for several fields the board,
I think the question is a newbie but it's something I want to learn to do.

Comment: the idea is to use one of the filters that brings ng -table and make it look in all fields, have tried to make a filter with filter but do not work well as well not updated the data for each page in the ng -table

Answer (score 0):

The exact behaviour you are looking for is accomplished by using the filter object '$' attribute. Like this:

```
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    // ...       
    filter: {
      $: 'filter string'
    },
  }, {
    // ...
  });
```